# Simular varios clientes en nodejs

Tags: nodejs

¿Cómo puedo simular varios clientes usando `nodejs`? ¿Hay algún módulo?

Comment: ¿que clase de prueba tienes en mente? me suena bastante vaga la expresión "simular varios clientes". no se si quieres usar node como cliente o como server.. o ambos, ¿puedes explicar de que trata la simulación?

Comment: Yo uso karma con mocha. Un ejemplo concreto de uso y de prueba con Firefox, Chrome, Safari e IE se puede ver en https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-to-html

Answer (score 2):

yo lo hice con mocha, para eso debes de instalarlo de manera global con el siguiente comando.

```
npm install -g mocha
```

También debes de tener la siguiente librería.

```
npm install socket.io-client
```

Después de tener estos dos elementos, en tu proyecto deberas de crear una carpeta llamada /test con un archivo llamado test.js, en mi caso este archivo contiene lo siguiente.

```
var mocha = require('mocha');
var io    = require('socket.io-client');

describe("conexion", function () {

    var server,
        options ={
            transports: ['websocket'],
            'force new connection': true
        };

    var con_client = [];
    //conexiones de los usuarios simulados
    var num_client = 10;

    beforeEach(function (done) {
        // start the server
        // dirección de archivo a testear
        server = require('../app').server;

        done();

    });

    it("conexion de clientes", function (done) {
        //emulacion de clientes
        for (var i = num_client; i >= 0; i--) {
            con_client[i] = io.connect("http://localhost:3000", options);

            con_client[i].once("connection", function () {
                con_client.disconnect();
            });
        };

        //tiempo limite de ejecución de la prueba
        //colocar un tiempo menor al de ejecución por parte
        //del comando
        //cmd: mocha --timeout 15000
        setTimeout(done, 10000);

    });

});
```

En la variable `var num_client = 10;` especificamos cuantos clientes quieres simular y en esta linea `server = require('../app').server;` especificamos la ruta del archivo al cual le realizaremos la simulación de clientes, `setTimeout(done, 10000);` esta linea determina el tiempo de la simulación, debe ser menor a la ejecución de la prueba de mocha que veremos mas adelante, si no lo hacemos así, mocha nos mostrara el siguiente error.

> Error: timeout of 10000ms exceeded. Ensure the done() callback is being called in this test.

Para que no salga ese error ejecutamos el siguiente comando con 15 segundos.

```
mocha --timeout 15000
```

Donde 15000 es el tiempo que estará activo la prueba.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí hay una imagen de los 10 clientes que simule, Espero que te ayude.